# Force carbonation function

Tags: carbonation, co2, force-carbonation

Does anyone have a formula for forced carbonation level (dissolved CO2) as a function of beer volume, temperature, CO2 psi, and time? I assume that this function would be logarithmic with respect to time, while psi, temperature, and volume might be scalers.

Another input to the function would be the area of the headspace-to-beer junction. Lets assume this is constant and held at the internal cross section of a Cornelius keg.

I've looked at several forced carb charts and they all seem to leave beer volume and time at psi setting out of the equation.

Basically what im looking for is a method for estimating the duration at which to leave the kegs at the increased pressure without going over the desired level of carbonation. But also, as someone somewhat new to kegging, I'd like to be able to discern level of carbonation given knowledge of the carbonation process. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php/Carbonation_Tables

Braukaiser has a great page on carbonation, including tables formulated with different units, and the formula itself.

Comment: The formla on Braukaiser is definitely a step in the right direction, but the function doesn't have time as an input. Thanks for sharing this link.

Comment: I'd be keen on the time input too.

Comment: It seems that the carbonation process is not so simple. See the following link to the chemical engineering subreddit. There are a ton of good suggestions regarding experiment design and fitting the data to a trend line: https://www.reddit.com/r/ChemicalEngineering/comments/e9gge9/dissolved_co2_as_a_function_of_time/?sort=confidence